# Why does broadcast onreceive not trigger in the background?

Tags: android

I want to monitor changes in the network proxy and detect the network when changes occur. I enter the log in onreceive. When I am in activity, it can log normally. However, when I go to the settings interface to set the proxy, the onreceive log will not be triggered. It will be triggered immediately after returning to the activity. Why is this?

Thank you in advance to everyone who answers this question！！！！

This is my code

```
public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("NetworkChange", "onReceiveTest 代理接收器接收到了: "+ intent.getAction());

        InternetConnectionStatusHelper internetConnectionStatusHelper = InternetConnectionStatusHelper.getInstance(context);
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        ProxyInfo proxyInfo = connectivityManager.getDefaultProxy();
        if (proxyInfo != null) {
            String host = proxyInfo.getHost();
            int port = proxyInfo.getPort();
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
            internetConnectionStatusHelper.setmProxy(proxyInfo);
            internetConnectionStatusHelper.checkConnection();
            Log.d("NetworkChange", "onReceive has: 代理");
        }else {
            internetConnectionStatusHelper.checkConnection();
            Log.d("NetworkChange", "onReceive: 无代理");
        }
    }

}
```

The receiver I registered with the service

```
public class NetworkService extends Service {
    private final String TAG = "NetworkChange";
    BroadcastReceiver networkReceiver;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PROXY_CHANGE");
        networkReceiver = new NetworkReceiver();
        registerReceiver(networkReceiver,intentFilter);
        Log.d(TAG, "服务创建了");
      
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

This is very important to me. Can you please tell me if there is anything wrong with my code?

I tried using wakelock and that didn't work either
I expect it to be able to run the code in onreceive in the background

This is the permission I have obtained

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_VPN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

I'm sorry that my description may be a little wrong. Onreceive will be triggered once when the network is switched in the background. After being triggered once, onreceive will not be triggered when the network is switched later.

Comment: In android 7 and above services can not be alive in background more than 5 seconds.

Comment: I register directly in the activity, but onreceive cannot be received.

Comment: I also tried front desk service

Comment: Try add ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION action to the IntentFilter

Comment: I just tried it, but still no success

Comment: Add these permissions : android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE and android.permission.INTERNET to the manifest file and if you trying register your reciver in an activity don't unregister it in onStop or onPaus . you must register it in onCreate().

Comment: Yes I did this, I had these permissions added in the manifest and I didn't unregister anywhere

Comment: Did you try adding this intent in AndroidManifest file, because this is system broadcast

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DEVICE_POLICY_VPN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

your code is correctly capturing the ACTION_PROXY_CHANGE broadcast, but this broadcast is sent only once when the proxy settings change and not continuously for subsequent changes.

If you want to continuously monitor network changes or proxy changes, you might need to consider other approaches, such as periodically checking the network status or using a ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback to monitor network changes. Keep in mind that continuous monitoring may have an impact on battery life, so it should be used judiciously and efficiently.

upadte ----------

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Network;
import android.net.NetworkCapabilities;
import android.net.NetworkRequest;
import android.util.Log;

public class NetworkMonitor {

    private final Context context;
    private final ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback;

    public NetworkMonitor(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        networkCallback = createNetworkCallback();
    }

    public void startMonitoring() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                .build();

        connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, networkCallback);
    }

    public void stopMonitoring() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback);
    }

    private ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback createNetworkCallback() {
        return new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                super.onAvailable(network);
                // Network is available, handle the change
                Log.d("NetworkChange", "Network is available");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLost(Network network) {
                super.onLost(network);
                // Network is lost, handle the change
                Log.d("NetworkChange", "Network is lost");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback to monitor network changes, but it does not monitor the agent. That’s why I want to achieve it through broadcasting

Comment: Ive added some code hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your code, OnAvailable can indeed be triggered after setting the proxy。But how do I determine whether it is a proxy network?And the previous problem still exists. It will only be triggered for the first time in the background, and will not be triggered later.

Comment: https://github.com/white-jwj/NetworkDetection/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/networkdetection/demo      This is the github link of my code. Can you please help me take a look?